# How to get optimal starlight ceiling

Tags: ceiling

How do you create this kind of starlight ceiling? Is this panels, paint or fiber optics?[image]

Comment: Can be one or more of the three.  A good painter can do it, most people use ready made panels, and if you want to get real fancy and have it change, can probably do something with fiber optics or have a simple projection system.

Comment: @crip659: yep. Depends on budget, available skills, and exact effect desired. If not sure. Try a small panel and see if you like the result; if not try something else. Fiber optic is mist expensive and usually prettiest, and allows done animation/flickering/cloud effects. Projection is simple but getting a true black background and even lighting is tough. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

I did something like that in my childrens' bedrooms many years ago.  Bought long-glow paint that was almost white during the daytime, and used hundreds/thousands of tiny dots on the white ceiling of different random sizes and locations.  Most were really tiny (just a few millimeters at most in size), but I did try and randomize the sizes a bit so it didn't look like they were all the same size, as the larger dots appeared brighter than smaller ones, and the actual sky doesn't have all stars the same magnitude anyway.

It took a long time, but looked really good.  Didn't have the look of the milky way, but the kids loved it. Since I'd used white paint, it was pretty much invisible during the daytime, but after a day of bright light in the room, it was pretty impressive once the lights were off and it was dark in the room.  Using long-glow paint did help it persist for several hours.

I suppose if you want to try and do a milky way look, you could try doing a bit of dry-brushing type technique with cotton balls to give more clouds of light, but I didn't go to that much effort.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what is in the picture is a wall [decal muraL](https://www.limitlesswalls.com/products/mural/starry-night-sky-milky-way-galaxy-with-stars-and-space-dust-in-the-universe-long-exposure-photograph-with-grain-wall-mural_171490?dfw_tracker=52618-178630849_adobe&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA6byqBhAWEiwAnGCA4BeYL4DhJ327If9EmB3m6e6W3fPDUYfvHcmuCikCJvF3ujO2I33I9BoC8t0QAvD_BwE).